# Having trouble Accessing Docker Container Running on Minikube VM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, request, localhost, minikube

I am trying to run a docker container on a minikube virtual machine, but I'm having trouble accessing the container.

Outside of minikube, I run container like so

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p 6717:6717 <image-name>
```

So, I'm mapping port 6717 of my host machine to port 6717 of the machine where docker is running.

And I would usually use `http://locahost:6717` to send requests to the application running inside the container (which is a Fast API application, but I don't think that matters that much).

While using minikube, however, I can't seem to access the container.

I checked out this post: [Unable to connect to running docker containers (minikube docker daemon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989739/unable-to-connect-to-running-docker-containers-minikube-docker-daemon).

The person seemed to have the issue issue that I had, but the suggested solution doesn't really solve my problem. In other words, instead of using localhost, I used the minikube VM's IP address like this

```bash
> minikube ip
```

Then tried to send requests to `http://<minikube-ip>:6717`. However, this also doesn't work.

I ssh'd into the VM like this:

```bash
> minikube ssh
```

and I can confirm that the application inside docker is running since I can do something like this successfully:

```bash
> curl http://localhost:6717
```

What am I missing exactly? I don't understand why I can't connect to the docker container using the minikube VM's IP address.

Comment: Can you Refer to this [doc](https://pwittrock.github.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841630/19230181) by Affes Salem, might help you.

Comment: Can you please try this command `minikube ssh -- sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6717 -j DNAT --to <minikube-ip>:6717`, if it did not work can you please show share the output of `docker ps -a | grep <your-container-id>`